# Azure Mobile Services generate secure hash

Tags: node.js, azure, cryptography, sha, azure-mobile-services

How can I generate a SHA-1 (or some other hash) for a string inside a Mobile Services API method?

I couldn't find any Crypto APIs like in .NET.

Comment: You should consider SHA-2. It has much stronger collision resistance than SHA-1. (If you're using them for password hashing, both are equally wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the [`cypto.createHash()` function](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.3/api/crypto.html#crypto.createHash) and the associated [`hash.update()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.3/api/crypto.html#hash.update) and [`hash.digest()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.3/api/crypto.html#hash.digest) functions?

Usage:

```
  var crypto = require('crypto')
      , sha1sum = crypto.createHash('sha1');

  sha1sum.update("foo");
  console.log(sha1sum.digest('hex'));
  // "0beer45dfsab5ea389fd0sdfuj309bcis9"
```